# Callback not working the second time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am facing an issue with my code below where the call back is getting called only the first time DocText is set. Subsequently setting the DocText is not calling my callback. I am trying to reset the html of the browser by setting the same string to the DocText property.

WebBrowser class

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentTextProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("DocumentText", typeof(string),
 typeof(WebBrowser), new
 FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty,TextChangedCallback));

 private static void TextChangedCallback(DependencyObject
 dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
 dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
 { 
    var control = (WebBrowser)dependencyObject;
    control._browser.DocumentText = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue.ToString();
 }

 public string DocumentText 
 {
     get { return (string)GetValue(DocumentTextProperty); }
     set { SetValue(DocumentTextProperty, value); }
 }
```

Factory class that creates the instance of the web browser is using the browsers set binding to bind the dependency property to "DocText"

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(documentTextProperty))
 {
     browser.SetBinding(WebBrowser.DocumentTextProperty,     documentTextProperty);
 }
```

And the documentTextProperyt is being set like this from the ViewModel class

```
 DocText = "some html string";

 public string DocText
 {
     get
     {
         _docText = if(html != null? html: string.empty);
         return _docText;
     }
     set
     {
         docText = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(() = DocText);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Notification is not going back to control(WebBrowser). Please check whether INotifyPropertyChanged is properly implemented. I checked equivalent code in my system and it is properly working.

```
    public class MaskedTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentTextProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("DocumentText", typeof(string),
         typeof(MaskedTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), TextChangedCallback));

    private static void TextChangedCallback(DependencyObject
    dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
    dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var control = (MaskedTextBox)dependencyObject;
        control.Text= dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue.ToString();
    }

    public string DocumentText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DocumentTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DocumentTextProperty, value); }
    }
}

<StackPanel Margin="50,5,5,50">
        <local:MaskedTextBox x:Name="text1" DocumentText="{Binding ElementName=text2, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="text2"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here if you edit second text box it is updating first one by calling the callback method properly!

Comment: Thanks Kiran but I need to be able to have binding defined in the factory class between the dependency property and the View Model property so that when using code i change the value of the View Model property the browser control updates.

Comment: Hello mate, I am not very sure may be in that factory method you are trying to set the value to the Dependency Property of your control. If this is true, then you are not using the proper method to set the value. SetBinding method is used to set the binding to a control. On the other hand SetValue method is used to update the value of the dependency property of  a control. Below are snippet to demonstrate further using elaborate comments.

Comment: //DocumentText="{Binding TestString, Mode=OneWay}"
            myControl.SetBinding(MaskedTextBox.DocumentTextProperty, new Binding() { Source = DataContext, Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(TestString)), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });

            TestString = "testing it";

            //this will show in control 'testing it' because the control is binded to TestString Property"

            myControl.SetValue(MaskedTextBox.DocumentTextProperty, "Another testing");

            //this will show in control 'Another testing' because the control property value is updated programetically here"

Comment: I have isolated my issue. Its with the Dependency property. I need the call back to happen when the value of my property is set (even if the value is the same). Now its happening only if the value is changes.

Comment: public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentTextProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("DocumentText", typeof(string),
 typeof(WebBrowser), new
 FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty,TextChangedCallback));